# Nested lambda capture doesn't work in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, lambda, c++11

I have compiled this using Visual Studio 2010 compiler and it has compiler error issues on nested lambda capturing the variables captured already by the first lambda:

```
    Functor& fn, const WorkData& workData

    group.run([&fn, workData](){
    async_future<ProcessorResult> future([&fn, workData]() -> ProcessorResult{
    ProcessorResult result = fn.Process(workData);

    return result;
    });
});
```

I get:

```
**error C3480**: '`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda3>::fn': a lambda capture variable must be from an enclosing function scope
```

It seems that the compiler does not like that I try to capture inside the future instance the variables captured already by the group.run() method.

If I create local copies it works:

```
    group.run([&fn, workData](){
    Functor& fnlocal = fn;
    WorkData workDatalocal = workData;

    async_future<ProcessorResult> future([&fnlocal, workDatalocal]() -> ProcessorResult{
    ProcessorResult result = fnlocal.Process(workDatalocal);

    return result;
    });
});
```

Is this behavior conformant ? I always need to make copies of captured variables in order to capture the same variables on a nested lambda ?

Comment: oog -- features like this are the reason I don't have much interest in C++11.

Comment: :-) Yes, but they fix it

Comment: they fix *what*? I wasn't talking about the compiler bug, I was talking about the warts attached to the language.

Comment: @JasonS you cannot make things right if one doesn't even try :-)

Comment: @JasonS: Yes, it's so terrible to be able to define simple function inline, where they are easily readable and comprehensible, instead of having to write whole new classes with boilerplate code or external functions, which you have to track down. Yes, it's such a burden to write C++11 code where the argument to a thread function or algorithm is inline and thus easily visible. /sarcasm.

Comment: Lambdas are a universally good feature. If you think they're a wart, then I suggest that you learn to program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the Visual Studio 2010 C++ compiler.  Here is the connect issue tracking it

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/725134/nested-lambda-expressions-can-not-capture-entities-of-enclosing-lambda-expressions

It's currently marked as fixed in the next version

Answer (score 4):

It's not conformant to the final draft, but it *is* conformant to the wording at the time at which they were implemented- i.e., it's not really a VS defect but neither is it exactly Standard. The next version, colloquially known as vNext, will have an implementation updated to use the latest wording.